# symmetric matrices using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, programming

Write a Matlab function that takes a matrix and test if it is symmetric or not. The function will
return the number "1" if the matrix is symmetric and "0" if it is not.

```
function B=symmet(A)

A = input("Enter a square Matrix");

[r, c]=size(A);

for i = 1:r

    for j = 1:c

        if i~=j

          if(A(i,j) == A(j,i))

            disp('1')

          else      

            disp('0')

          end

        end

    end

end
B
end
```

Now how I can define a function in MATLAB that answer my question. In which, just if I give this function any square matrix I receive only output 0 or 1 related to symmetry.

Comment: Might be easier to check if $A - A^{\top}$ is 0.

Comment: This is not a programming site. You should check $r =c$ before looping.

Comment: @sudeep5221 yes you are right, but am trying to do it without using the idea of A=A'

Comment: In that case, just check if $A(i,j) \sim= A(j,i)$. If this is true, break and return false. Otherwise if the loop is completed, return True.

Comment: @JeanMarie Really? thank you, I have undeleted it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will instead want to initialize the variable to 1 (i.e., default as symmetric) to start and then switch it to 0 only if you find out the matrix is not symmetric.

So first open a new file and name it something like `isSymmetric.m`. This will generate a MATLAB script for you to use.

In the body, you define the function name at the top, which has to match your file name. You also define your return variable (called `answer` below).

```
function answer = isSymmetric(matrix)
  answer = 1;
  for i = 1:size(matrix,1) 
    for j= 1:size(matrix,2)
      if(A(i,j) != A(j,i))
        answer = 0;
        break;
      end
    end
    
    if (answer = 0)
      break;
    end
  end
```

Notice in the code, the function returns `answer = 1` by default, and only changes `answer = 0` if it runs into something non-symmetric.